# How does one prove that a multivariate function is univariate?

Tags: real-analysis

The question resembles [How does one prove that a multivariate function is constant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69294/how-does-one-prove-if-a-multivariate-function-is-constant) but appears to be more difficult.

Suppose that $u\colon\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous function such that at every point $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$ at least one of the following is true:

1. the partial derivative $\displaystyle \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ exists and is equal to $0$.
2. the partial derivative $\displaystyle \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ exists and is equal to $0$.

Does it follow that $u$ depends only on one of two variables $x,y$? In other words, can we prove that either 1 holds for all points or 2 holds for all points?

So far I can prove this only under the additional assumption $u\in C^1$.

**Edit:** Here is a proof of the $C^1$ case.

Claim 1: If $u_x(a,b)\ne 0$ for some $(a,b)$, then $u_x(a,y)=u_x(a,b)$ for all $y\in\mathbb R$.

Claim 2: If $u_y(c,d)\ne 0$ for some $(c,d)$, then $u_y(x,d)=u_y(c,d)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Once Claims 1 and 2 are proved, it follows that the premise of one of them never holds, otherwise both derivatives would be nonzero at $(a,d)$.

By symmetry it suffices to prove Claim 1. The set $E=\{y\in\mathbb R\colon u_x(a,y)=u_x(a,b)\}$ is closed by the continuity of $u_x$. Also, if $t\in E$ then $u_x\ne 0$ in some neighborhood of $(a,t)$ (again by continuity), which by assumption yields $u_y=0$ in this neighborhood, meaning $u$ does not depend on $y$ there. Thus, $E$ is also open. We conclude with $E=\mathbb R$, proving the claim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question was answered in the affirmative by A.M. Bruckner, G. Petruska, D. Preiss, and B.S. Thomson in *The equation $u_xu_y=0$ factors*, Acta Math. Hungar. 57 (1991), no. 3-4, 275-278. Actually, they prove a more general result, for separately continuous functions. The proof for continuous functions is quite simple (once you see it, of course!). The main idea is in the following lemma.

**Lemma 1.** Let $R$ be a closed axes-aligned rectangle $R$, and let $p$ be a vertex of $R$. Then the connected component of $p$ in the set $E=\{q\in R\colon u(q)=u(p)\}$ meets a side of $R$ not containing $p$.

Assume Lemma 1 for now.

**Lemma 2.** In the notation of Lemma 1, $u(r)=u(p)$ for some vertex $r$ adjacent to $p$.

Proof: We may assume $p$ is the bottom-left vertex and the component of $p$ in $E$ meets the right side of $R$. Then $E$ separates the bottom-right vertex $r$ from the sides not containing it. This leads to a contradiction unless $u(r)=u(p)$. Lemma 2 is proved.

Now the proof is finished as follows. Suppose $u$ attains distinct values at two points $p_1$, $p_2$ lying on the same vertical line. For each point $p$ on this line pick $i\in\{1,2\}$ such that $u(p_i)\ne u(p)$. Applying Lemma 2 to all rectangles with $p$ and $p_i$ as vertices, we see that $u$ is constant on the horizontal line through $p$. Since $p$ was arbitrary, $u$ is constant on all horizontal lines. **QED**

It remains to **prove Lemma 1**. The proof involves *comparison with square cones*, which are functions of the form $f(x)=c\|x-a\|_1=c(|x_1-a_1|+|x_2-a_2|)$ with $c>0$. It also uses, perhaps surprisingly, the [equality of components and quasicomponents](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11412/any-two-points-in-a-stone-space-can-be-disconnected-by-clopen-sets/11423#11423) in compact Hausdorff spaces (such as $E$).

We may assume $p$ is the bottom-left vertex of $R$. Suppose the component of $p$ in $E$ does not meet either the top or the right side of $R$. Then there exist disjoint sets $U,V$ which are open in $R$ and cover $E$ in such a way that $U$ contains $p$ and $V$ contains both the top and the right side of $R$. There exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $|u(q)-u(p)|\ge 2\epsilon \|q-p\|_1$ for all $q\in R\setminus (U\cup V)$. The set $K=\{q\in U\colon |u(q)-u(p)|\le \epsilon \|q-p\|_1\}$ is compact and nonempty. Let $r$ be its largest point in the *lexicographic order*. The points $q\in U$ such that $q_1\ge r_1$ and $q_2\ge r_2$ satisfy $|u(q)-u(r)|\ge \epsilon \|q-r\|_1$. In particular, this holds when $q$ approaches $r$ from the right or from above (note that the construction of $U$ makes such approaches possible). But either $u_x$ or $u_y$ vanishes at $r$ -- a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The following might be a counterexample, though I get stuck at a certain point:

We can let $f_r(x)$ be a fat Cantor function, where $0<r<1$. We define such functions iteratively as follows:

Set $f_r^0(x) = x$. The recursively define $$f_r^{n+1}(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}0, & x\leq 0 \\ \frac{1}{2}f_r^{n}(x), & 0\leq x \leq \frac{1-r}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2}, & \frac{1-r}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{1+r}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}f_r^n\left(\frac{2}{1-r}x - \frac{1+r}{1-r}\right), & \frac{1+r}{2}\leq x \leq 1 \\ 1, & x \geq 1 \end{matrix}\right.$$ Set $f_r(x)$ equal to the limit (which is easy to see is uniform), and note that each $f_r(x)$ is continuous.

Now, set $$u(x,y) = \left\{\begin{matrix}f_{1/3}(x), & y\leq 1/3 \\ f_y(x), & 1/3 \leq y \leq 2/3 \\ f_{2/3}(x), & y \geq 2/3 \end{matrix}\right.$$

It is not difficult to see that $u$ is continuous. However, that $u$ satisfies the hypothesis in question is a bit more difficult. We have that where $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ exists, it is clearly $0$. So we need only worry about the places where $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ does not exist. Suppose this is the case at some $(x_0,y_0)$. If $y_0 < 1/3$ or $y > 2/3$, it is clear that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 0$. The tough case is when $1/3 \leq y_0 \leq 2/3$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)$ does not exist. If $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)$ does exist, then it should be $0$, because it is not hard to see that $u(x_0,y)$ is constant either over a small interval $[y_0,y_0+\epsilon)$ or $(y_0-\epsilon,y_0]$. However, I see no immediate reason why the partial derivative should exist. Maybe this is where the example stops being a counterexample, or maybe somebody can complete the proof.

Comment: Interesting example: I'll have to think about it. There's a small typo in the first displayed formula: the second line should have $\frac{1}{2} f_r^n\left(\frac{2}{1-r}x\right)$

Comment: However, this is not a counterexample. Indeed, if a point $(a,b)$ falls in a gap in Cantor set, then both $u_x$ and $u_y$ vanish there. Let $(a,b)$ be a point where $u_y$ either does not exist or is nonzero (such points must exist since the function depends on $y$ in some places). By above, $(a,b)$ is not in a gap. It follows that the derivative $u_x(a,b)$ does not exist.